# How to remove curved border and inset box shadow from Material UI TextField React component?

Tags: css, reactjs, input, textfield, box-shadow

Here's the input field:

[image]

It has this inner shadow in it and curved borders.

Here's the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class SearchInput extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchInputFieldValue: ''
        };
    }

    textFieldOnChangeSearch(event) {
        this.setState({searchInputFieldValue: event.target.value});
        this.props.phoneBookSearch(event.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TextField
                    underlineShow={false}
                    hintText="Hae.."
                    onChange={this.textFieldOnChangeSearch.bind(this)}
                    value={this.state.searchInputFieldValue}
                    style={{
                        boxShadow: 'none',
                        height: '57px', 
                        width: '460px',
                        /*
                        borderStyle: 'solid',
                        borderColor: '#2375BB',
                        borderWidth: '2px',
                        */
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
                    }}
                    />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchInput;
```

Here's how it shows in the browser's inspect:

If I uncomment the commented part of the style in the code it shows like this:

[image]

As you can see, here's the blue border that I'd like but the curved borders and the inner shadow is still showing in the background.

How to remove them?
Even box-shadow: none !important; in web tools doesn't remove it.

Comment: Can you share a jsbin? Will be easier to inspect.
As Material UI creates a hierarchy of elements to show a text field, the style might need to be applied on a different element to effect the visible style.

Comment: Ok, I will in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please inspect the element where the `boxShadow` and `borderRadius` are being applied. When you find it, accordingly you can use different attributes of the Material UI Textfiled and effect its style.

If the style is on the main element then your style attribute should have worked.

I suspect it to be on `input` element which you can change by using `inputStyle` attribute of `TextField`.

Also check the [docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field) for more element specific style attributes option.

Comment: That's right. my boxShadow: 'none' should've been in the inputStyle attribute, not in thte style attribute. That fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#test {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#test:focus {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;

}
```

```html
<input id ="test" type="text">
```

This may help

Answer (score 1):

You can define an `outline` property to `none`, while `focus` on that `input` text-field.

```css
'&:focus': {
            outline: "none"
           },
```

this will perfectly works for me. !!

Answer (score 1):

In `TextField` component add `variant="outlined"` and `InputProps` bellow:

```
InputProps={{
  ...params.InputProps,
  classes: {
    notchedOutline: classes input
},
startAdornment: (
  <SearchIcon />
),
```

Also make sure to use `makeStyles` from `@material-ui/core/styles`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  input: {
    padding: '15px 0px',
    border: 'none'
  },
  list: {
    maxHeight: 300,
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    "& .MuiAutocomplete-option": {
      padding: 0
    },
  }
}));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of text should be replaced with the text they contain, or augmented by it, because images of text are not searchable, aren't accessible, and can't be copied and used by people trying to benefit from your answer. When adding an answer to an older question with an accepted answer it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.